# How to syntax highlight via Less

Tags: syntax-highlighting, less

is there a way to syntax highlight a file I see in Less?

actually I'm using this command to open an xml file (and sometimes a series of them)

```
less htmleditors/htmleditors_config.xml
```

or

```
less [multiple files]
```

I'd like to stay in Less (to learn that program better and to use my knowledge of :n and :p for next/previous navigation)

But it also want some kind of basic syntax highlighting – at least show the comments differently. Do you know any way to do it?

Comment: Possibly a solution to your problem, not exactly an answer to your question: The moar pager does syntax highlighting out of the box, and has somewhat less-compatible key bindings: https://github.com/walles/moar. Disclaimer: I wrote moar myself, so of course I like it.

Answer (score 166, accepted):

You can use [GNU's source-highlight](http://www.gnu.org/software/src-highlite/), as shown [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/src-highlite/source-highlight.html#Using-source_002dhighlight-with-less) (path may differ, see below):

```
 export LESSOPEN="| /usr/bin/src-hilite-lesspipe.sh %s"
 export LESS=' -R '
```

As of Debian Stretch and Fedora 25, package names and script paths differ

- Debian:

  ```
  sudo apt install libsource-highlight-common source-highlight
  dpkg -L libsource-highlight-common | grep lesspipe
  # /usr/share/source-highlight/src-hilite-lesspipe.sh
  ```
- Fedora:

  ```
  sudo dnf install source-highlight
  rpm -ql source-highlight | grep lesspipe
  # /usr/bin/source-highlight/src-hilite-lesspipe.sh
  ```

Comment: I retrieve the following error message when I run `less ~/.zshrc`. Error: `src-hilite-lesspipe.sh: line 9: source-highlight: command not found`. I run this on MacOSX.

Comment: @JJD Did you install source-highlight?

Comment: OSX:  `brew install source-highlight`;  `export LESSOPEN="| /usr/local/bin/src-hilite-lesspipe.sh %s"`.  Note the path change.

Comment: On Debian: `sudo apt-get install source-highlight`, `export LESSOPEN="| /usr/share/source-highlight/src-hilite-lesspipe.sh %s"`, `export LESS=' -R '`

Comment: small caveat: source-highlight does not currently support markdown.

Comment: also `alias more='more -R '` or `more` will stop working.

Comment: As @dhulihan wrote, source-highlight does not support markdown.  But [highlight](http://www.andre-simon.de/doku/highlight/en/highlight.php) supports markdown and many more. OSX: `brew install highlight`; `export LESSOPEN="| /usr/local/bin/highlight --out-format=xterm265 %s"`

Comment: Note that the Debian packaging is actually a bit broken:  The script itself is in `libsource-highlight-common`, but calls `source-highlight` from eponymous package, but does not declare dependency on it (split as they are now, they seem to actually form a circular dependency).

Comment: For Raspbian installs, use `export LESSOPEN="| /usr/bin/source-highlight-esc.sh %s"`.

Comment: After installation and setting the env var, I still get no syntax coloring in less, unless I set the env vars in `.bashrc`, strange that setting it in `/etc/profile.d/less.sh` does not work; the vars are read and I can see them loaded(added `echo` in `/etc/profile` to see which files are loaded). Someone to help? It's a login shell with putty.

Comment: `source-highlight` requires a file (a named pipe won't work) for syntax highlighting, so something like `pipeline | less` won't work.  For a solution see [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1332042/365890).

Comment: Is it possible to combine this with the default lesspipe(.sh) somehow?

Comment: @dhulihan [GNU source-highlight - Bugs: bug #46542, Add support for Markdown](https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?46542) We are all welcome to send a pull request

Comment: This works fine but it breaks the ability to use default `lesspipe` for binary files, so instead I'd suggest something that uses this solution only for binary files (i.e. something like https://gist.github.com/textarcana/4611277#gistcomment-2859093), or just another script that does the same.

Answer (score 140):

Best of both previous answers: you can invoke system default editor from within less, by pressing <kbd>v</kbd>.

Comment: Wow! This is amazingly useful!

Comment: Curses that opened Nano on my Ubuntu box!

Comment: Then set $EDITOR or $VISUAL to vim (or emacs, or gedit, or joe, or ed, or mined, or…).

Comment: @jamesc FYI, you can enable syntax highlighting in Nano, [here](http://askubuntu.com/a/90026/425899) is how.

Comment: @CaptainMan Nope nope nope! I change the default back to vim like Daniel H said! :D

Comment: Does not work when using pipes: `Cannot edit standard input  (press RETURN)`.

Comment: @ks1322 Yep, if you're for example viewing a `man` page using `less` as the pager, or if you're just piping something through `less`, you can't edit that. _Maybe_ you could hack your way there by using `LESSEDIT` or some other environment variable, but I'm not aware of any way.

Answer (score 41):

```
pygmentize somefile.ex | less -R
```

or

```
function cless () {
    pygmentize -f terminal "$1" | less -R
}
```

Pygmentize comes as a part of the [Pygments Python syntax highliter](http://pygments.org/).

Comment: `pygmentize` also works with the `LESSOPEN` stuff mentioned in other answers here.

Comment: To get `pygmentize`, you need Python and then you can install `pygmentize` with `pip install pygments`.

Comment: To get `less` to use `pygmentize` for syntax highlighting use: `which pygmentize 2> /dev/null >&2 && export LESSOPEN="| pygmentize -g -f terminal256 %s"`. `-g` to make it work with pipes (`less <(diff -u file1 files)`). It's available in `community/pygmentize` package for `arch linux`, and in `python-pygments` for `debian`.

Comment: I like the output of `pygmentize`, but found it to be too slow. I came up with [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1332042/365890) which is faster and still 256-colour pretty.

Comment: you can also just pipe to pygmentize first, e.g. `cat myfile | pygmentize | less -R`

Answer (score 22):

As others have said, you can use the power of vim.  But importantly, you can do so without learning how to use vi/vim.

Vim comes with a `less.vim` script that works pretty well as a replacement for less, with full color syntax highlighting.  It uses `less` keybindings (just hit 'q' to quit).

It had a few problems, so [I improved it](https://github.com/huyz/less.vim). Here's a screenshot from [my blog post on it](https://web.archive.org/web/20130409201746/http://huyz.us/2011/a-less-like-pager-with-color-syntax-highlighting/) (archived 2013-04-09; [original](http://huyz.us/2011/a-less-like-pager-with-color-syntax-highlighting/) throws 503):

[image: screenshot of https://github.com/huyz/less.vim]

Comment: Awesome! But as I couldn't find the script right away I'd like to share the command for locating it: `find /usr/share/vim -name 'less.sh'` which is taken from this gist: https://gist.github.com/chauncey-garrett/9773770

Comment: Adding to @yoshi's comment, to quickly add a `vimless` command (following the nomenclature of `vimdiff`), do: `ln -s $(find /usr/share/vim -name 'less.sh') /usr/local/bin/vimless`

Comment: The link is 404!

Comment: @acgtyrant Should be fixed now; the Internet Archive thankfully has it.

Answer (score 17):

I think that you should use a text editor.  I like vim myself.  That will give you LOTS of power when viewing files and then when you want to edit them you will already know the basics.

Here are some of the advantages of using a text editor (specifically vim):

- syntax-highlighting
- powerful movement commands
- find
- jump to specific location in a file (called a mark)
- folding (useful when you just want to see function stubbs)

To open your file in readonly mode use this:

```
vim -R <file name>
```

Here is a basic navigation guide:

```
j - move down one line
k - move up one line
h - left one char
l -right one char

ctrl-f - forward one page
ctrl-b - back one page

/<something> - search for something
n - next of whatever you searched for
N - next (search backwards) of whatever you searched for

:q - quit
:q! - quit without saving
:w - save
```

Here is a link for more information:

http://www.viemu.com/a_vi_vim_graphical_cheat_sheet_tutorial.html

Just to recap, if you will use unix vim is pretty fundamental.  I have heard that learning vim is like learning to type.  It is the next most useful tool you can learn for programming.

(Just to avoid editor wars you could also look into emacs or another editor, however I *personally* prefer vim)

Comment: I second this. Vim launches as fast as less, and many of the keyboard shortcuts (e.g., search, next page, previous page) are identical.

Comment: Just FYI, on a lot of systems, `view` is an alias for `vim -R`.

Comment: When you have a file of several hundred megabytes, such as for example a huge XML file, you'll really prefer to use `less` rather than opening the file in Vim, Emacs or any other editor. That's the whole point of opening a file in `less`. You can also perform text searches in `less` as you do in Vim, BTW.

Answer (score 10):

I was also searching for this and found another solution using Vim:
http://ubuntu-tutorials.com/2008/07/14/use-vim-as-a-syntax-highlighting-pager/

The post is rather old, so now on more recent distros vim 7.2 is shipped and the .bashrc will read:
alias vless='vim -u /usr/share/vim/vim72/macros/less.vim'

Comment: MacVim comes with a shell script that you can use directly, located in: /Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/runtime/macros/less.sh

Comment: This feature is documented in Vim itself under [`:help less`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/various.txt.html#less)

Answer (score 9):

I'm glad to announce a new package, [**e2ansi**](https://github.com/Lindydancer/e2ansi), that provides
syntax highlighting support for pagers like `more` and `less`.

The package use the mother of all text editors, [Emacs](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs), to
perform the actual syntax highlighting. As an added bonus, all other
conversions normally performed by Emacs -- like uncompressing files --
is also performed.

## Example

The following is the result of viewing a file using `less` and
`e2ansi`:

[image: Example]

## Configuration

The package provides a command-line tool `e2ansi-cat` that starts
Emacs in batch mode, opens files, syntax highlight them, and renders
the result using ANSI sequences.

You can integrate this into `less` by setting the following variables
to, for example (the location of your init file may vary):

```
export "LESSOPEN=||-/usr/local/emacs --batch -Q -l ~/.emacs -l bin/e2ansi-cat %s"
export "LESS=-r"
alias "more=less -X -E"
```

In the configuration above, `less` restores the original terminal
window content whereas `more` simply output new content after the
prompt.

Note: If you use an old version of `less`, it might not support the
`||` or the `-` syntax, in which case you may need to use simply
`LESSOPEN=|/usr/local/emacs ...`.

## Using `less` in pipes

The "-" character in `LESSOPEN` indicates that the input filter should
also be used when piping text into `less`. In this case, Emacs can
only rely on text itself (and not a file name). Fortunately, Emacs
provides a system for this. In addition, the provided file file
`e2ansi-magic.el` sets up additional file types. For example:

[image: Pipe example]

## Why use Emacs?

- Emacs has support for virtually all programming languages and
  structured text formats. In most cases, the syntax highlighting
  support is excellent.
- You can easily add support for more languages and formats, or modify
  existing packages to suit you needs.
- Emacs support color themes. When using `e2ansi`, the colors in the
  theme is preserved when viewing a file in `less`. You can pick a
  suitable color theme from a number of sources, or design your own.
- If you use Emacs as your editor of choice, you will get the same
  highlighting in the editor as you get when viewing a file using
  `less` (minus limitations in ANSI sequence format and the terminal
  window).
- `less` will take advantage of Emacs features that perform automatic
  conversion, for example uncompressing files. In fact, you can teach
  Emacs to perform any kind of conversion like automatically convert a
  binary file to human readable form using an external tool.
- You can view files located on other machines by using Emacs' syntax
  for remote access like `/USER@HOST:FILENAME`.

## Useful links

- `e2ansi` is distributed on [Melpa](http://www.melpa.org) and can be installed using
  the standard Emacs package system
- `e2ansi` is hosted on [GitHub](https://github.com/Lindydancer/e2ansi)
- The `e2ansi` page on the [Emacs Wiki](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/e2ansi)
- The home of [`less`](http://www.greenwoodsoftware.com/less).

## Operating system notes

- On MS Windows, the console does not natively support ANSI sequences.
  Fortunately, the `less` application is capable of rendering them. I
  am not aware of any contemporary binary distribution of `less` for
  MS Windows and the provided build files is hard to use. Fortunately,
  it's easy to build `less` using [CMake](http://www.cmake.org), see [this text](https://github.com/Lindydancer/e2ansi/blob/master/doc/LessWindows.md) for
  details.
- OS X distributes an ancient version of `less`. Fortunately, it's
  easy to build a modern version directly from the source.

Comment: For OS X, I'd recommend using the package manager *brew* [http://brew.sh/] with *brew dupes* [https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-dupes] to install up-to-date versions of things like `less`.

Comment: "powered by emacs" -- running whole VM just to look at a file? ;-) and +1

Answer (score 7):

If you have [GNU Source-highlight](http://www.gnu.org/software/src-highlite/) installed you can use the following command to highlight the syntax of a single file:

```
$ src-hilite-lesspipe.sh yourfile.xml | less -R
```

Comment: Can `src-hilite-lesspipe.sh` receive input via a pipe as well?

Answer (score 4):

After installing GNU's [source-highlight](http://www.gnu.org/software/src-highlite/source-highlight.html) (package `dev-util/source-highlight` on sabayon/gentoo), I configured those envs in `/etc/bash/bashrc.d/my-less-src-highlight`:

```
#default:    export LESSOPEN="|lesspipe %s"
#don't like: export LESSOPEN="| /usr/bin/src-hilite-lesspipe.sh %s"
#default:    export LESS=" -R -M --shift 5"
export LESSCOLOR=always
export LESSCOLORIZER=/usr/bin/src-hilite-lesspipe.sh
```

I did not like to replace `lesspipe` because that has other features. Concatenation did not work.

Comment: thanks for your answer -- couldn't find documentation of LESSCOLOR, until I realized this must refer to [Gentoo's lesspipe](https://github.com/Rafiot/Lesspipe), rather than the `lesspipe` included with the GNU less package on [Debian systems](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/less/lesspipe.1.en.html). There is also a much more mature-looking project on github with the same name...

Answer (score 3):

I found [`highlight`](https://gitlab.com/saalen/highlight) which:

- Supports multiple colour schemes and 256-colours
- Works on STDIN (unlike `source-highlight`)
- Is much faster than `pygmentize`

[image: Screenshot]

Here is a script I call `highlight-less-wrapper` which includes `.bashrc` instructions on how to setup `less` to use it automatically.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Have highlight read from STDIN if '-' is given as filename

# Setup - Add to .bashrc:
# LESSOPEN='|-highlight-less-wrapper "%s"'
# export LESS=-FMRXis

# Usage:
# $ less file
# OR
# $ pipeline | less

warn () { printf "%s: %s\n" "$(basename "$0")" "$*" 1>&2; }
die () { warn "$@"; exit 1; }

# Argument checking
case $# in
    0)
        # Allow `exec $0` for less setup
        echo "LESSOPEN='|-$(readlink -f "$0") "'"%s"'\'
        exit 255 ;;
    1)
        # Only one argument is expected.
        # less will invoke multiple times given multiple files.
        file=$1
        if [[ $file != - && ! -r $file ]]; then  # less passes '-' for STDIN
            die "Cannot open $file for reading"
        fi ;;
    *)
        die "Expected only one argument" ;;
esac

# Run highlight
# highlight will read from STDIN when given a null filename
run_highlight () {
    highlight --force -O truecolor --style aiseered "$1"
}

if [[ $file == - ]]; then  # Run on stdin
    run_highlight ""
else
    run_highlight "$file"
fi
```

Comment: instead of this script, this seems simpler (from http://www.andre-simon.de/doku/highlight/en/integration.php):
```
export LESSOPEN="| $(which highlight) %s --out-format xterm256 -l --force -s solarized-light --no-trailing-nl"
export LESS=" -R"
```

Comment: @timotheecour, I really like that as it has line numbers.  It seems to break the setting of tab width.  I have LESS as '-R -x4' which works with source-highlight-esc.sh

Answer (score 2):

`source-highlight` has a `.sh` script located in `/usr/share/source-highlight/*.sh`. I've created a symbolic link to it with name `hcat` in `/usr/bin`.

It shows highlighted output in terminal (console) – `hcat` is highlighted cat.

**How to:**

```
[me@this]<bash><~> 43 
21:23 Fri Apr 19 > sudo apt-get install source-highlight

[me@this]<bash><~> 28 
21:03 Fri Apr 19 > ll /usr/share/source-highlight/*.sh
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 432 May  1  2012 /usr/share/source-highlight/src-hilite-lesspipe.sh*

[me@this]<bash><~> 29 
21:04 Fri Apr 19 > sudo su
root@this:/home/me# cd /usr/bin/
root@this:/usr/bin# ln -s /usr/share/source-highlight/src-hilite-lesspipe.sh hcat

[me@this]<bash><~> 36 
21:07 Fri Apr 19 > hcat test.xml
```

Answer (score 2):

Using OS X 10.9 (Maverick) this would do the trick:

- brew install source-highlight (Assuming brew is installed - http://brew.sh)
- sudo nano /etc/launchd.conf

  > ```
  > setenv LESSOPEN="| /usr/local/bin/src-hilite-lesspipe.sh %s"     
  > setenv LESS=' -R '
  > ```

  (Add to /etc/launchd.conf)
- reboot

Answer (score 1):

If you want **the same syntax highlighting you use in Vim**, but for some reason you prefer to use `less` as your pager, you can use this script: https://github.com/rkitover/vimpager

The basic usage would be:

```
vimpager file.txt
```

or

```
vimcat file.ext | less -R
```

You can use `-c` to pass extra commands which aren't in your `.vimrc` (e.g. selecting a different colorscheme).  The full command I use is:

```
vimcat -c 'set cmdheight=20' -c 'hi! clear Normal' -o - "$FILENAME" | less -REXS
```

Beware: If your Vim asks you to press Enter when it starts up, you won't see the prompt, but nothing will happen until you press Enter!  The `cmdheight` trick above can help to mitigate that.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same question and I landed hear, read all answers and the following is what I finally did to have syntax highlighting everytime I use `less` or `most`:

```
sudo apt install source-highlight
```

Then I went and created an alias for my `less` and `most` (I use ZSH, but you can add aliases for your `.bashrc` file if you use bash):

```
vim ~/.zshrc
```

(*For those who might get stuck in vim: press <kbd>i</kbd> to go to edit mode, when you are done press <kbd>Esc</kbd> then <kbd>:</kbd> then <kbd>x</kbd> and finally 
<kbd>Enter</kbd> to save the changes*)

And paste the following lines for debian-based distros (like Debian, Ubuntu, Mint, etc.):

```
alias most='AliasFuncLess() { unset -f AliasFuncLess; $(dpkg -L libsource-highlight-common | grep lesspipe) "$1" | less -R };AliasFuncLess'
alias most='AliasFuncMost() { unset -f AliasFuncMost; $(dpkg -L libsource-highlight-common | grep lesspipe) "$1" | most };AliasFuncMost'
```

or for RPM distros (Redhat, Fedora, Centos):

```
alias most='AliasFuncLess() { unset -f AliasFuncLess; $(rpm -ql source-highlight | grep lesspipe) "$1" | less -R };AliasFuncLess'
alias most='AliasFuncMost() { unset -f AliasFuncMost; $(rpm -ql source-highlight | grep lesspipe) "$1" | most };AliasFuncMost'
```

**Remember** to close the terminal and open it again to make sure alias is created.

Now you can enjoy the colors:

```
most yourFile.xml
```

Answer (score 1):

With https://gitlab.com/saalen/highlight or `app-text/highlight` on Gentoo already installed, configuration below seems to work simple and beautiful:

```
$ env | grep LESS      
LESS=-R -M --shift 5           
LESSOPEN=| command highlight -O ansi %s
```

Answer (score 0):

In mac, you can just type `view filename`, does similar thing like less.

Comment: With OSX, `view filename` just launches `vim` by default - slightly different key bindings to `less` (see other answers to this question for more details).

Comment: `/usr/bin/view` is literally symlinked to `/usr/bin/vim` on macOS. But yeah, Alan is not wrong, I guess it "does similar things" technically speaking! ;)

Answer (score 0):

There is a [`fish` shell plugin](https://github.com/decors/fish-source-highlight) to help integration. However, you still need to install the lib (see [brandstaetter answer](https://superuser.com/a/71593/174465))

```
fisher install decors/fish-source-highlight
```